# Elastic Search 1.7.3 Nested filter: matching terms in an array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query for the following document in my elasticsearch:

```
"amenity": [
        "Free Wifi",
        "Free Breakfast",
        "Veg Only",
        "Swimming Pool",
        "Newspaper",
        "Bar",
        "Credit Card",
        "Pickup & Drop",
        "Gym",
        "Elevator",
        "Valet Parking"
      ],
      "dodont": [
        {
          "do_or_dont": "Do",
          "what": "Vegetarians"
        },
        {
          "do_or_dont": "Do",
          "what": "Family"
        },
        {
          "do_or_dont": "Dont",
          "what": "Loud Music"
        },
        {
          "do_or_dont": "Dont",
          "what": "Booze"
        }
      ]
```

and here is the query I have written:

```
"filter": {
    "and": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "nested" : {
            "path" : "dodont",
            "filter" : {
              "bool" : {
                "must": [{"and" : [
                        {
                            "term" : {"dodont.do_or_dont" : "Do"}
                        },
                        {
                            "term" : {"dodont.what" : "Vegetarians"}
                        }
                    ]},
                    {"and" : [
                        {
                            "term" : {"dodont.do_or_dont" : "Do"}
                        },
                        {
                            "term" : {"dodont.what" : "Family"}
                        }
                    ]}]  
              }

            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now this query returns empty result, but when I change the "must" to "should" in the bool in above code, it returns the above document as the result (there is only 1 document matching this filter the one shown above), but ideally, the "must" condition should return the above document, I want to pass multiple objects for Do's and donts and I only want the results which match all of them, but I am not able to do so. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split out the two conditions on your nested document, since each element of the `dodont` nested array is conceptually a separate document:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "and": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dodont",
            "filter": {
              "and": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "dodont.do_or_dont": "Do"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "dodont.what": "Vegetarians"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dodont",
            "filter": {
              "and": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "dodont.do_or_dont": "Do"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "dodont.what": "Family"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it works. But Im curious, what is the reason for this? Those objects are in the same array right? Why do we need to treat them as separate documents? Thanks.

Comment: It's the way ES has implemented nested elements, the short answer is that each element of the array must be independent from each other, hence separate (hidden) documents. You can find more info about this very subject in the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects).

Comment: right thanks, so is there a better way to do this? What if I define the data structure as an array of Do's and Dont's? It should make the queries simpler right?